# Scheme "an instance isn't a procedure error"

Tags: scheme

Function *f* has parameters i < integer>and j < function>. Function *j* takes an integer as a parameter returns an integer. Why does the code in *f*

```
(if (equals? (j i) 1) (...) (...))
```

give the error "instance: an instance isn't a procedure -- can't apply it"? Shouldn't (j i) be returning a integer value?

Comment: Yes it should. So it seems like `j` is not a function or that `(j 1)` doesn't return an integer.

Comment: Did you mean `equal?` (note the missing `s`)

Comment: This message is generated in `tiny-clos.rkt` which is part of *swindle* so you have probably mixed up functions and classes. Post the definition of *f* please.

Comment: And remember that it's only one namespace in Scheme so if you define a local variable that happens to have the same name you are shadowing it. eg. `(let ((+ 10)) (* + +)) ;==> 100`. It's very easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you have to use a logical operator to compare more than one condition.

example

```
(if (**and** ( equals? (j i) 1) (equals? (j 2) 3) (...) (...) )
; Consecuence

; Alternative
)
```